# Typography "display" not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

New function "display" is not responsive as i want. On small devices the text is under the image, screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsrhD.jpg
Code:

```
<!-- IMAGE -->
    <div class="d-none d-md-block">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/bg-img.jpg'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="caption hidden-sm-down">
            <center><h1 class="display-3">ZespÃ³Å‚ SzkÃ³Å‚ Elektrycznych</h1></center>
            <center><h1 class="display-4">im. prof. Janusza Groszkowskiego</h1></center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't do that for you, you still have to write media queries for responsive typography.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#responsive-typography

Be aware, example in docs is written in sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div class="d-none d-md-block">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/bg-img.jpg'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="caption hidden-sm-down">
            <h1 class="display-3 text-center">ZespÃ³Å‚ SzkÃ³Å‚ Elektrycznych</h1>
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center">im. prof. Janusza Groszkowskiego</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

First of all, remove `<center></center>` from your code and replace with Bootstrap alignment class.

Then for mobile you can use media query to make text smaller:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .display-3 {
       font-size: 14px; 
    }
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with media queries, you can read more here about them: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Hope this helps.